# Cannot send correct response when dealing with queries with MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, express

I encountered a problem when dealing with queries' error handling for a MySQL database in NodeJS :
I searched a bit about callbacks in JavaScript and async functions but I cannot figure out how am I suppose to get the correct error message that I want in a type of situation, here it is :

```js
auth.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    console.log('POST register');
    const user = {email: body.email, password: body.password, name: body.name, firstname: body.firstname};
    my_db.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', user, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            is_err = false;
        }
    })
    is_err = true;
    if (!is_err)
        res.json({"msg" : "user already exists"});
    else
        res.json({"token": "Token of the newly registered user"});
})
```

Typically I want that the json formatted message {"msg" : "user already exists"} is sent as a response when a user already exists. I tried booleans, numbers, async functions but seems like I am doing this terribly. And I cannot do `res.json()` inside the query ! How am I suppose to do it ?

Comment: `my_db.query()` is asynchronous. You need to put all the rest of the code in the callback function.

Comment: Does it mean that I am supposed to move the last 4 lines in another function ?

Comment: Move it into the function with `if (err)`

Comment: You don't need the `is_err` variable. Just put the first `res.json()` call inside that `if`.

Comment: `if (err) { console.log("ERROR"); res.json(...); } else { res.json(...); }`